# Replacing a file extension and everything after it using wildcards in Notepad++

Tags: replace, notepad++, wildcard

**What I have:**

```
<object class="imageSettings" data="../assets/FOM_SVG_140.svg" height="434.501282" style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;display: block;margin: auto;" type="image/svg+xml" width="486.747274">
```

**What I want:**

```
<object class="imageSettings" data="../assets/FOM_SVG_140.png >
```

I have numerous SVG files with different information between **.svg** and **>**. Is there an easy way to replace the text? I've tried various wildcards, but I haven't gotten the desired result. I'm fairly new to wild cards. I've tried:

```
.svg*>
\.svg.*$
\svg.+$
\svg.*$
```

Comment: What you want isn't valid HTML, are you sure about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\.svg".+?>`
- Replace with: `.png">`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\.svg       # extension, dot have to be escaped
"           # double quote
.+?         # 1 or more any character, not greedy
>           # close tag
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]